# How to get end of process time per processor using "pool" in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use Multiprocessing library in Python to distribute a function over multiple cores. To do that I use "Pool" function, but I want to know when each processor has completed its work.

Here is the code :

```
def parallel(m,G):

   D=0
   for i in xrange(G):
        D+=random() 

   return 1*(D<1)

pool=Pool()

TOTAL=0
for i in xrange(10): 
    TOTAL += sum(pool.map(partial(parallel,G=2),xrange(100)))
print TOTAL
```

I know how to use time.time() in normal situation, but what I need is to know when each core has completed is part of the job. If I put a time stamp directly in the function I will get many time values without knowing on what core it is processed.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure your question has an answer, since the subprocesses created by the `Pool` won't shut down until the pool is closed (or the main process shuts down). I don't think there are any exposed functions to hook into the sub-process shutdown code. Are you sure you need that information?

Comment: Oh I see, but maybe there is another way to distribute the work and be able to time.time() each processes? I am a beginner in Python and I don't know advanced functions. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I'd suggest to rename the post to `How to get end of processing time per processor using “pool” in Python?`, note processing vs process. At least that was the question I was answering in my post :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may return the completion time along with the actual result from `parallel` and then pick the last timestamp for each worker.

```
import time
from random import random
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process

def parallel(m, G):
    D = 0
    for i in xrange(G):
        D += random()
    # uncomment to give the other workers more chances to run
    # time.sleep(.001)
    return (current_process().name, time.time()), 1 * (D < 1)

# don't deny the existence of Windows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    TOTAL = 0
    proc_times = {}
    for i in xrange(5):

        # times is a list of proc_name:timestamp pairs
        times, results = zip(*pool.map(partial(parallel, G=2), xrange(100)))
        TOTAL += sum(results)

        # process_times_loc is guaranteed to hold the last timestamp
        # for each proc_name, see the doc on dict
        proc_times_loc = dict(times)
        print 'local completion times:', proc_times_loc

        proc_times.update(proc_times_loc)            

    print TOTAL
    print 'total completion times:', proc_times
```

However when jobs are that simple you may find that calling `time.time` each time consumes too much of CPU time.)

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a bit difficult to use Multiprocessing functions because the documentation is very limited. I will read about dict(...) to understand what it does and yes time.time is consuming, so I have to add a kind of "If statement" to reduce the calling frequency.